# Grails 3.3: Could not find com.novadge.plugins:grails-twilio:0.1.4

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I trying to install the plugin grails-twilio from [grails plugin portal](http://plugins.grails.org/plugin/novadge/grails-twilio) but I receive the following message:

> | Error Error initializing classpath: Could not find com.novadge.plugins:grails-twilio:0.1.4.

Any advice on installing this plugin?

The dependencies I put from is:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.novadge.plugins:grails-twilio:0.1.4'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please check with plugin [repo](https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/com/novadge/plugins/grails-twilio/). Version `0.1.4` is not available in the plugins repository.

Check with following code:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.novadge.plugins:grails-twilio:0.1.0'
}
```

Refer [plugin page](http://plugins.grails.org/plugin/novadge/grails-twilio) and [github](https://github.com/Novadge/grails-twilio) for additional configuration

Hope this will you.

Answer (score 0):

I would go to the issues section on the plug-in page, and raise this same issue, linking back to this stack overflow page, including a full stack trace, and maybe a link to a sample app, demonstrating the issue.

In my experience I've found that while, a core set of plug-ins are very good, others can be hit or miss. Sometimes I look at a plug-in, as just a good starting point, and dive into the code. For Twilio in the past I've implemented it's use with just it's library, and it wasn't difficult at all.